# How to trigger Ajax ( <iron-ajax > ) call in polymer?

Tags: ajax, polymer

I just want to trigger the ajax inside some javascript function

My code is here:

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="app"> 
<iron-ajax auto url="{{ path('polymer_get_file') }}" handle-as="json" last-response="{{ '{{attachmentResponse}}' }}">
</iron-ajax>
  <vaadin-grid items="{{attachmentResponse.results' }}">
    <table>
      <colgroup>
        <col name="index">
        <col name="file"/>
        <col sortable name="file"/>
        <col name="type"/> 
      </colgroup> 
    </table>
  </vaadin-grid></template><script> function onClick (){
   // Here i need to trigger iron-ajax } </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could call `<iron-ajax>`'s [`generateRequest()`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax#method-generateRequest):

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
  <button on-tap="onClick">Send</button>
  <iron-ajax id="ajax" ...></iron-ajax>
</template>

<script>
  var app = document.getElementById('app');
  app.onClick = function() {
    this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
  };
</script>
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  const app = document.getElementById('app');
  app.onClick = function() {
    this.response = null;
    this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
  };
  
  app.json = function(obj) {
    return JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
  };
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.11.3/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
</head>
<body>
  <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    <button on-tap="onClick">Send</button>
    <iron-ajax id="ajax"
               url="//httpbin.org/get"
               last-response="{{response}}"></iron-ajax>
    <pre>[[json(response)]]</pre>
  </template>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/apoXye?editors=1010)

Comment: If there are multiple ajax calls on a page, wouldn't this trigger all the ajax requests on the page?

Comment: @Hari You mean multiple `iron-ajax` elements? The `$` map contains a 1-to-1 reference of id to element, so no, it does not trigger all `iron-ajax` requests on the page. You can try it in the codepen linked in the answer.

Comment: So, the "ajax" in "$.ajax" should match with id attribute.

Comment: Yes. See Polymer's [Automatic node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding) feature